# Undefined method 'model_name' in index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, controller

I have a Dashboard controller and in the index method i have @message = Message.new( Message is my model )...In my index.html.erb i have a form

```
<%= form_for @message do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :message %><br>
    <%= f.submit "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

and i get an error at first line of the form "undefined method `messages_path'"...

I don't have a new method in my controller

Pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a `resources :messages` route in `config/routes.rb`? The error is happening when Rails tries to create the form's submission route from the class of the argument to `form_for`

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification will probably be better than me for in depth explanations

Answer (score 1):

that error occurs when you did not specified respective routes in routes.rb file so just add
`resources :messages`

or if you want explicit route for some certain method add that in route file